# Issues scrolling horizontally in Java/Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I've gone through previous posts on this and am still having problems getting this to work.

I have a small scroll bar I need to move to the right so that I can access items I need to test. The code for the scroll bar is as follows:

```
 <div class="ngscroll-scrollbar" ng-style="styles.scrollbar" style="height:
 6px; bottom: 3px; left: 3px; opacity: 0; width: 126.05px; transition: 
 opacity 0.3s ease-in-out 0s, border-radius 0.1s linear 0s, height 0.1s 
 linear 0s, bottom 0.1s linear 0s; position: absolute; cursor: default; 
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) none repeat scroll 0% 0%; border-radius: 3px;"></div>
```

The scroll bar is inside a container, I don't know if that's an issue.

```
 <div class="ngscroll-scrollbar-container" ng-show="!isTouch" ng-
 style="styles.scrollbarContainer" style="bottom: 0px; left: 0px; width: 
 100%; height: 12px; margin-left: 0px; position: absolute; transition: 
 background 0.3s ease-in-out 0s; border-radius: 6px; background: transparent 
 none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">
```

Here is my code:

```
 WebElement scroll = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/div[2]/main/div/ui-view/ui-view/div[2]/div/div[1]/su-flight-filters/div/aside/div/section/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div"));
 JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver; 
 js.executeScript("document.getElementsByClassName('ngscroll-scrollbar').scrollRight += 50", "");
```

I do not get any errors but the scroll bar does not move either. I've tried values of 50, 250 and 400.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`.getElementsByClassName()` returns a collection. Try

```
js.executeScript("document.getElementsByClassName('ngscroll-scrollbar')[0].scrollRight += 50", "");
```

to scroll the first matching element. You'll have to check and make sure the first match is the one you want.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work either. I'm not sure how to handle that collection, is there any way I can print the contents out to the console to see what it contains?

Comment: You can run `document.getElementsByClassName('ngscroll-scrollbar').length` in the console and see how many matches there are to that locator. You should be able to run any of this JS in the console and see that it works.

Answer (score 0):

Use Action class to move the slider, i find this as the convnent way
choose value of X is any its depends of width of your slider and if you use for loop to drag pointer on multiple position

```
 WebElement slider = driver.findElement(By.id("slider"));
    int width=slider.getSize().getWidth();
    Actions move = new Actions(driver);
     Action action = (Action) move.dragAndDropBy(slider, 30, 0).build();
    action.perform();
```

Comment: I think the problem is this particular scroll bar has to be clicked on then dragged over. Will the above do that? I tried it and I see it seem to get activated but it doesn't slide. The bar is 205 wide and 6 high.

Comment: or use this code by specifying range in in for loop
move.moveToElement(slider).click(slider).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_RIGHT).perform();

Comment: or use this one below in the action object, specify number of pixels to be dragged
move.moveToElement(draggablePartOfScrollbar).clickAndHold().moveByOffset(0,numberOfPixelsToDragTheScrollbarDown).release().perform();